# Using KeyRemap4MacBook to bind a keyboard key to a scroll action?

Tags: macos, macros, unity-game-engine

Basically, I want to bind a certain letter to scroll up the mouse reel, and do so continuously if I hold the key continuously. I need it to work even if other keys are being pressed at the same time, and only work on a certain window title/tab title in the browser.

I basically want to emulate the function of the autohotkey program for the "Attack On Titan Tribute Game"'s reeling function.

An AutoHotKey equivalent is available at:
http://fenglee.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=7548
(Which may be offline due to unknown reasons, might have to wait)

Basically, if you download the application, set Reel In to the "x" or "e" key, it works regardless if other keys are being held. Just make sure you uncheck the checkbox so it can work in any window. It basically scrolls down for you. It also includes the source.

Or.. if I can use any other *free* application to do the same thing, that'd be nice.

All I want is the scrolling function and it has to be specific to a window/plugin/etc. and be able to be triggered while holding down other keys.

Comment: Can you share with us what you've tried?

Comment: I didn't try much. I did try to edit an xml file in there with something online relating to my problem.. but I couldn't get it to work. I have NO experience with it.